# PatternSyntax Exception,Dangling meta character '+' near index 0

Tags: java, arrays, exception, pattern-matching, matcher

I am trying to use a `Matcher` for some reason, but sometimes it gives me the `PatternSyntax Exception` . i know in my case it means that `+` is a reserved character and should escape it. but my string has no such character in it at all:

```
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile(test,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        StringBuffer testing=new StringBuffer (node.getNodeValue());
        matcher=p.matcher(testing);
        if(!matcher.hitEnd())
             {
         if(matcher.find())
          {

          i++;
          }
               }
```

the exception is thrown at `Pattern p=Pattern.compile(test,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

the `test` string is just some words or characters which are not in any case a `+`
 or `*` etc.

here is the list of words that `test` will be replaced with them in a for-loop:

**EDIT**

I used the answer of **Elliott Frisch** however now a strange exception is happening:

```
         for(int j=0;j<index2;j++)
                  {
    test = (test != null) ? test.toLowerCase() : null;
str = (str != null) ? str.toLowerCase() : "";
if (str.contains(test)) 
{


           X[Index]= keArrayList.indexOf(test);
                Index++;
            }   

  }

             int[] X=new int[100000];

           private static final double[]  Y=new double[100000];

              for(int i=0;i<Index;i++)
             {
        felan=Y[X[i]];

             }
```

here although the both loop indexes are much smaller than `100000` but in first iteration I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

is this anything related to the if condition or what?

Comment: What is `test`, exactly?

Comment: as i explained in the question, it is some words that i extracted from a random Web page

Comment: It's important to know the _actual contents_.

Comment: its a very long list and it varies from page to page but if tyou want I can show you for one page that gives this exception

Comment: @August please look at the update

Comment: @lonesome we don't need to see your list we need to see your pattern.

Comment: @EddieB there is no special pattern except it use matching exact word ,case-insensitive. I thought thats quite obvious

Comment: @lonesome You're missing the point. We fix code... not ideas.

Comment: @EddieB i added more detailes if thats what you meant. though the exception happens at first line

Comment: Your use of `Pattern` here seems wrong. You should probably be using `String.contains()`. And you should not be using `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if so sure why not write an answer to this question of mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `StringBuffer` ([`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) has been preferred since Java 1.5). Also, your `Pattern` isn't being reused; so compiling it seems pointless. Finally, if you just want to test if your `node` matches a certain number of "tests" in your loop I suggest you use something like

```
String str = node.getNodeValue();
test = (test != null) ? test.toLowerCase() : null;
str = (str != null) ? str.toLowerCase() : "";
if (str.contains(test)) {
    i++;
}
```

Comment: ok, I used your answer, but , though im not sure, but there is another exception happening. right after this if im using a for-loop which uses the variables that are assigned in the if above. although the idexes are high enough, but in first iteration it gives me array out of bound exception. I udate it in my question. maybe you can have a look to see if this is related to this answer or not

Comment: X[I] isn't a valid index for Y. And that's a new question.

Comment: understood. but why it is not valid? since the value of X[i] wont exceed the Y[] dimension, how it become not valid?

Comment: @lonesome if you're getting an index out of bound exception then it does (by definition) - if it's negative or larger then Y.length you'll get that exception.

Comment: yea, since the Y[] length is quite big, I was wondering if there is another reason it gets the exception which you mentioned a negative index and yes, it was the case

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a loop counter just use a while statement... simply print the results while the matcher finds matches... Your error is probably because of the increment in the if condition... there's no increment natively in an if statement without an initialized variable. However you're not revealing all the code so I'm just presuming...

Further, I can't tell whether the compile argument, 'test' is a literal value or a variable, but the parameter requires *[a regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String))*.

```
    public static String list = "..."; // long list..

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( ".+" ); // some pattern 

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( list );

        while( matcher.find() ) {
            System.out.println( matcher.group(0));
        }

    }
```

Comment: I already revealed all the codes that contains the **pattern** and **matcher** there is no other thing. in fact, i read a web page content, then trying to match its content with a keyword, when the matching happens, an index increases . something like this. that **i** is an integer to count the number of matching that occurred

Comment: @lonesome The string literal 'test' is not a valid pattern. a Pattern is a java RegEx. You need to read up on the syntax. [Java RegEx Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: i know, but i simply wnted to make pattern as simple as just a word. did i do that wrong?

Comment: @lonesome Please see the updated answer... Pattern.compile takes a String regular expression as a parameter...

Comment: i see the update. so you mean it is wrong to use **string** instead ?

Comment: You need an 'expression' as a parameter. Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b"); :: I'm not angry... just [RTFM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) :-)